# How can I pass an instance of a basetype and then check what kind of subtype it is?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I've got a base class and three subtypes that derive from that class (see example below).

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{
    string name;
    string color;
}

public class Car : Vehicle 
{
    int nrofwheels;
}
public class Train : Vehicle 
{
    int nrofrailcars;
}
```

To make one of my method as generic as possible, I'd like to pass the base type as parameter and then detect hat subtype it is inside my method like this:

```
public static void main(string[] args)
{
    public Car c = new Car();
    public Train t = new Train();

    public CheckType(Vehicle v)
    {
        if(v.GetType()==typeof(Car)) Console.Write(v.nrofwheels);
        else Console.Write(v.nrofrailcars);
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work, why and what else can I try?

[edit] I know that the class examples aren't complete, but I'd figured that its not necessary for this purpose.

Comment: What doesn't work? What is the type returned? And what is the value for `v`?

Comment: You should not do that. Instead you should make `CheckType` use a method or property on the base type to do its job, so that you can use regular inheritance and polymorphism. Checking the type of an object is an anti-pattern, you really shouldn't do it.

Comment: You defined `Car` as having `nrofwheels`, but later you say if it's a car, print `nrofrailcars`...

Comment: @PatrickHofman Only the fields of Vehicle are accessible now.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks for the insight, that indeed is a better thing to do. I didn't realise that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should refactor that class and move CheckType to Vehicle class and override it in descendant classes. And CheckType name is not the best one, it makes no sense since that method returns number of wheels / rails.

Something like this:

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{
    string name;
    string color;

    public abstract int CheckType();
}

public class Car : Vehicle 
{
    int nrofwheels;
    public override int CheckType()
    {
        return this.nrofwheels;
    }
}

public class Train : Vehicle 
{
    int nrofrailcars;
    public override int CheckType()
    {
        return this.nrofrailcars;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll refacter it like this. The name doesn't make any sense, I know. It was just for the sake of an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `as`. You forgot to cast the object to make the properties accessible:

```
public CheckType(Vehicle v)
{
    Train t = v as Train;

    if (t != null)
        Console.Write(t.nrofrailcars);
    else
    {
        Car c = v as Car;

        if (c != null)
            Console.Write(c.nrofwheels);
    }
}
```